# Overflow flex column child

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I'm struggling with problem of overflow flex child content in flex with flex direction column. I need to get scroll for flex child when it overflows with content. Everything is ok when my window size more than 1200px cause flex direction is row. But when screen is less than 1200px I switch flex direction to column and when content overflows flex child sections get inequal height.

My markup:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.row, .d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  @media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.row > * {
  flex: 1;
}

.col {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(234, 12, 88, 0.25);
  border: 1px solid rgba(4, 222, 188, 1);
  overflow: layout;
}

.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.auto {
  overflow: auto;
}

.tall {
  background-color: rgba(188, 255, 10, 0.23);
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col col-1 d-flex">
      <div class="auto w-100">
        <div class="tall">1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">2</div>
    <div class="col col-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One of possible solutions is to add `overflow: hidden` to `.col-1` which has overflow content, but I need to solve it without.

Is it possible to get scroll on flex column child when it overflows without `overflow: hidden` on flex item ?

https://codepen.io/ChatduChesire/pen/ZEQPWrQ?editors=1100

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Hi, no! Plain css

Comment: What are the heights of the boxes supposed to be in `flex-direction: column`?

Comment: How about adding this?  `.flex > * {  overflow: auto;  }`

Comment: Hi, Supposed they should be equal to each other. If there are 2 boxes 50% of parent height, if 3 boxes 33.3333...% etc

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin hi, I've tried this, but I need overflow inside child of flex child ( Everythig vorks fine if I add `overflow: hidden` to col-1,  but then I get anoter problems whit absolutely positioned elements

Comment: So I think you just need to add `min-height: 0` to the child.  Try this: `.flex > * { flex: 1; min-height: 0;` }

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin thank you, it works for me!